# PHP - Parse variable in zwei places and convert into nested arrays

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, explode

I'm a beginner and have been fighting with this for a while now. Quite straight forward, I'm getting a variable as follows back from my query:

$opvar ='11:00-20:30/-#11:00-13:00/18:00-20:30#11:00-20:30/-#11:00-20:30/-#11:00-13:00/18:00-20:30#11:00-13:00/18:00-20:30#11:00-13:00/18:00-20:33';

And need to parse/explode in two runs to separate at the "#" and then at the "/" and then have an array setup that matches the following to check if a restaurant is open at the the current time:

```
$opening = array(
array('11:00-20:30','-'),
array('11:00-13:00','18:00-20:30'),
array('11:00-20:30','-'),
array('11:00-20:30','-'),
array('11:00-13:00','18:00-20:30'),
array('11:00-13:00','18:00-20:30'),
array('11:00-13:00','18:00-20:33')
);
```

Tried a few things but just can't get it right - any help would be greatly appreciated, many thanks.

Comment: You can start with foreach loop and explode()

Comment: _“Tried a few things but just can't get it right”_ - please go read [ask]; you are expected to _show us_ what you tried, and give a proper problem description along with it.

Answer (score 0):

have the answer, neverthless thank you:

```
$opening = explode('#', $opvar);
foreach ($opening as &$d) {
    $d = explode('/', $d);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$opvar ='11:00-20:30/-#11:00-13:00/18:00-20:30#11:00-20:30/-#11:00-20:30/-#11:00-13:00/18:00-20:30#11:00-13:00/18:00-20:30#11:00-13:00/18:00-20:33';


$arrayA = explode("#",$opvar);
$resultarray = [];

for($i=0;$i<count($arrayA);$i++){
    
    $arrayB = explode("/",$arrayA[$i]);
    $resultarray[] = $arrayB;
}

print_r($resultarray);
```

Try This you will get required formate.